# Ionic1 with CocoaPods does not let me build my app in Xcode9

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, cocoapods, cordova-plugins, onesignal

I work on an older App of mine which is Ionic-v1. I install the OneSignal plugin  which is working now only with CocoaPods. At first all went fine, Android works flawless but I am not able anymore to build my IOS app because of CocoaPods. I can do what I want I keep getting the following error:

```
    ld: 72 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I lost the entire day trying to figure this out, I tried uncountable times any combination of “pod install, pod clean, pod disintegrate” etc. etc. but without any success.

I also found a post inside the ionic forum from @blakgeek and install his plugin “cordova-plugin-cocoapod-support” but keep getting the same errors. But with or without this plugin I keep getting the same error.

I would be happy if anybody can help me here because at this point I am pretty lost.

**Thank you in advance**

Xcode 9
Ionic 3.18 (But app is Ionic v1)cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.18.0
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.18.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0 
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android 6.3.0 ios 4.5.3
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.2.4
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.2 
ios-sim           : 5.0.6 
Node              : v8.9.1
npm               : 2.15.12 
OS                : macOS Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.0.1 Build version 9A1004
```

Environment Variables:
ANDROID_HOME : /Volumes/Mac External HD/Android/sdk

Misc:
backend : pro

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up deleting once again my entire ios platform for the xxx time and somehow solved it with the following steps.

a. deleted my complete ios platform 
b. deleted the onesignal cordova plugin
c. reinstalled the onesignal plugin
d. recreated my ios platform BUT forced version ios4.4.0 with the following command "`ionic cordova platform add ios@4.4.0`"
e. changed into my /platform/ios directory and made one "`pod install`"
f. opened xcode and build and run without any further issue.

Short explanation. I ended up with tone of duplicate symbol erros because I tried just to many things and manually added to many things. (cant recall what I did all) how ever I never paid attention in the number of duplicate symbols. I started out with just 2 which seems to be a known issue (thankx to this issue report https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/12849#issuecomment-328472880) but with my tests and trials I ended up with much more and got completely of track.

After clean install with ios@4.4.0 all worked fine for me. 
thank all for your attention...